# Matrix representation using Eigen vs double pointer

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have inherited some code which makes extensive use of double pointers to represent 2D arrays.  I have little experience using Eigen but it seems easier to use and more robust than double pointers.

Does anyone have insight as to which would be preferable?

Comment: What do you think double pointers are?  (Wait for it...)   Dynamic matricies, perhaps?

Comment: Eigen more intuitive?? care to explain why?

Comment: As void-pointer put it; These libraries are written so that linear algebra operations can be clearly expressed...

Comment: I understand that double pointers are dynamic matrices; I asked for insight as to if they would be preferable to the Eigen library.

Answer (score 1):

Both Eigen and Boost.uBLAS define expression hierarchies and abstract matrix data structures that can use any storage class that satisfies certain constraints. These libraries are written so that linear algebra operations can be clearly expressed and efficiently evaluated at a very high level. Both libraries use expression templates heavily, and are capable of doing pretty complicated compile-time expression transformations. In particular, Eigen can also use SIMD instructions, and is very competitive on several benchmarks.

For dense matrices, a common approach is to use a single pointer and keep track of additional row, column, and stride variables (the reason that you may need the third is because you may have allocated more memory than you really need to store `x * y * sizeof(value_type)` elements because of alignment).  However, you have no mechanisms in place to check for out-of-range accessing, and nothing in the code to help you debug. You would only want to use this sort of approach if, for example, you need to implement some linear algebra operations for educational purposes. (Even if this is the case, I advise that you first consider which algorithms you would like to implement, and then take a look at `std::unique_ptr`, `std::move`, `std::allocator`, and operator overloading).

Comment: The original implementation was done by a rather theoretical individual;  I believe it will be worth it to re-code the operations using Boost since it's already linked into the code base. Your input is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would recommend using Eigen over Boost.uBLAS. The latter is no longer actively maintained -- i.e. there is no function present to solve a linear system! uBLAS only supports some basic linear algebra functionality. Eigen is much more expansive, actively maintained, and it is competitive with Intel MKL (surpassing it on many benchmarks).

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely, for modern C++ you should be using a container rather than raw pointers.

#### Eigen

When using Eigen, take note that its fixed size classes (like `Vector3d`) use optimizations that require them to be properly aligned. This requires [special care](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html) if you include those fixed size Eigen values as members in structures or classes. You also [can't pass them by value](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPassingByValue.html), only by reference.

If you don't care about such optimizations, it's trivial enough to disable it: simply add

```
#define EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN
```

as the first line of *all* source files (.h, .cpp, ...) that use Eigen.

The other two options are:

#### [Boost Matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm)

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> m (3, 3);
```

#### [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<std::vector<double> > m(3, std::vector<double>(3));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input;  since the existing code is relatively small it may be worth it to modify and use containers.

Answer (score 1):

Remember Eigen has a Map capability that allows you to make an Eigen matrix to a contiguous array of data.  If it's difficult to completely change the code you have inherited, mapping things to an Eigen matrix at least might make interoperating with raw pointers easier.

Comment: That's perfect; mapping things over will definitely make it easier to work with.